# set a variable to a the folder path Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWLOAD in android

Tags: java, android, internal-storage

I can't seem to find an answer to this simple question.

How do I set a variable to contain the path string to the internal download directory of my app?

```
root = Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWLOAD;
```

Then I could access files within that directory by:

```
root+"/"+filename+".pdf"
```

I can open a file list but I don't understand what it is doing

```
public void showDownload(View view) {
    Intent i = new Intent();
    i.setAction(DownloadManager.ACTION_VIEW_DOWNLOADS);
    startActivity(i);
}
```

Comment: What does "the internal download directory of my app" mean?

Comment: When I download a file from my webservice it is saved to the apps download folder from what I understand. I have been going through a tutorial so I am unsure how to access this directory.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If all you want to do is list the files inside that directory you can do it like this:

```
File dir = Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment
        .DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS);
String dirPath = dir.getAbsolutePath();

String[] files = dir.list();
for (String file : files) Log.e("", "File: " + file);
```

Or like:

```
File[] files = dir.listFiles();
for (File file : files) Log.e("", "File: " + file.getAbsolutePath());
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Where do you use the dirPath String?

Comment: @silversunhunter ugh I don't. Just an example of getting a path. Did this work for you?

Comment: It did not.. No log was output in the loop. I must be missing something obvious here. I downloaded the file using this: `request.setDestinationInExternalFilesDir(mContext, Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS, fileName);`

Comment: @silversunhunter stupid question, but you do have the external write permissions right?

Comment: Yep. I set that as part of the tutorial I am using to learn how to download from the server.

Comment: Maybe it is not there and is in the download manager.  case `DownloadManager.STATUS_SUCCESSFUL:
                            //START Activity TO display the download image
                            Toast.makeText(mContext, "File: "+fileName+" has been downloaded.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                            break;`    I never see this success message and Here I do nothing with the file as instructed..

Comment: I was able to use your code to see other files in another directory. I am accepting the answer. The problem I am having is that I don't know where to look for the files I need. haha... Thank you for the help!!